# Get value from a table based on three columns and one row in that table?

Tags: excel

How can I get a value from a table based on three columns (country, company, scenario) and one row (months) in that table?

I don't want to create a concatenated ID row.

It is a numeric value so I could use SUMIF to get the right value based on three columns if it wasn't that I also need to use a row criteria.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I want to retrieve the value from the table below:

```
country company scenario jan-2015 ...
Germany Stiehl  standard value    ...
...     ...     ...      ...      ...
```

Comment: Can you make a 4th column that represents the month ?

Comment: Nope, the business users want a matrix layout

Comment: Can you add a piece of your data ? Do you want to use formula or VBA ?

Comment: I want to use a formula